# What is the number of ways to arrange people in a queue?

Tags: combinatorics

People are standing in a queue when viewed from the front, m heads are visible, and n heads from the end. What is  the number of possible arrangements such that m&n remains same when viewed from front and end respectively

Comment: Sounds more like a [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) question to me.

Comment: Do you want to write a program to find out? If so, have you tried? If so, are you running into any problems? If so, would you mind asking about those, rather than dumping your homework as-is?

Comment: @JeroenMostert. I am not asking you to do my homework

Comment: Then show us you've done yours. As posed, this is not a programming question, which is what SO is about.